# Is there a way to name an EBS snapshot created with a Cloudwatch Rule?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there a way to *name* an EBS snapshot created with a Cloudwatch Rule?

For instance, I have a cron-like rule:

```
31 10 ? * 3,6 * vol-0e743fcfd2f53198a
```

Which will create a snapshot of the data volume, every Tue and Fri on 10:31 UTC.

However, the snapshots are created with their Name field *empty*, which makes it difficult to know which snapshot belongs to which EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can accomplish this.  I'd recommend using Lambda to accomplish your goal.

I use it to create a snapshot of my root volumes, utilizing CloudWatch events to trigger them.  Here is a snippet of the python code:

```
snap = ec2.create_snapshot(VolumeId=volume['Ebs']['VolumeId'], Description=name_tag+today)
ec2.create_tags(Resources=[snap['SnapshotId']], 
Tags=[
    {
        'Key'   : 'Name',
        'Value' : name_tag
    },
    {
        'Key'   : 'Copied',
        'Value' : 'False'
    },
    {
        'Key'   : 'Customer',
        'Value' : customer
    }
])
```

[image: ss1]